# MYSQL LOAD AND INSERT FILE NAME

Tags: mysql, load

Im loading a csv file into a MySQL database using a load statement, can I in that same statement grab the filename and insert in a column called filename? like maybe declaring the filename then doing an update set right after

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Users\kpacheco.AD\Desktop\Projects\Wellcare\Weekly01272014\FINANCIAL\ RECOVERY\ GROUP\ -\ CONTESTATION\ 20140129.CSV' INTO TABLE TRACKING_INSERT FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' ignore 1 lines;

Answer (score 0):

If `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement was supported by prepared statements in MySQL, then you could do it simple (here is a list of supported statements - [Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)).

So, you should construct and execute your `LOAD DATA INFILE...` in application layer.

**Example:**

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv'
  INTO TABLE table
  (column1, column2)
  SET column3 = 'data.csv';
```

Comment: im sorry im not very advanced im not understanding

Comment: It is not possible to do it in MySQL. I suggest you to create command `LOAD DATA INFILE` in application (php, java, c#,...), and specify SET clause in LOAD DATA INFILE command to insert file name.